# Django asynchronous requests to remote api

Tags: python, django, api, asynchronous, tornado

I have the following code (simplified version)

```
for data in my_data_array:
  res = api_request(data)
  #write result to db
```

These request may take some time and there are a lot of them. How can I make each iteration of loop asynchronous and send progress with percentage of completed requests to the front-end with Django.
If I have to use Tornado or Celery, please give me the links with information how to integrate Django with them.

Comment: how did you end up solving this?

Comment: @bryanph , I have Redis cache and for each task I have **[task_id]_total** and **[task_id]_completed** keys. Each request (Celery task) when completed increments value `cache.incr(key, 1)`. And also I have download_progress() view-function which returns `compl = cache.get(key_compl), total = cache.get(key_total), compl/total`. The same way as in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Celery (or other async task queue). To integrate it with Django, see http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html. I recommend to use Celery with Redis, because Redis is often used as a cache, so you don't need to install another backend for Celery (mostly RabbitMQ).

To get the progress bar, count total number of tasks (`len(my_data_array)`), store the value in cache (e.g. key total_count) and add the second key (e.g. complete_count) with zero value. In every task that completes, increase the complete_count value.

Last step is to query the status. It is just a simple view that loads these two values from cache and returns to the user (html/json).